# is there a random number generator testing library for common lisp

Tags: common-lisp

I want to test a list, generated by a RNG, whether the list can be considered random.

I know that a single test wont do the deal, and a test-suite is required to have a reliable result. Furthermore I do known that there are a libraries/tools out there, like [DieHard(er)](http://www.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/General/dieharder.php), as far as I experienced they do not provide a neat interface for using from within lisp, neither could I find ports to lisp.

Therefore I want to know:

**What options do I have for testing a RNG using common-lisp (sbcl) on Linux?**

The random number generator to be tested is used within security relevant code, therefore the high standards have to be met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any rng test suite as comprehensive as dieharder in any language.  I would simply use CFFI to interface with libdieharder.